# C++ Functors explanation

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

Could you please explain following statements with example

> Statement1
>
> Ordinary functions have different types only when their signatures differ. However, function objects can have different types
> when their signatures are the same. In fact, each functional behavior
> defined by a function object has its own type. This is a significant
> improvement for generic programming using templates because you can
> pass functional behavior as a template parameter

Comment: What do you understand? What research did you do? Where does the statement come from, and where are the other statements?

Comment: More context needed.

Answer (score 5):

> Ordinary functions have different types only when their signatures differ.

Meaning that these functions both have the same type `int(int)`:

```
int f1(int);
int f2(int);
```

while this has a different type `void(int)`

```
void f3(int);
```

> However, function objects can have different types when their signatures are the same.

Meaning that these two classes are different types (as different classes always are):

```
class c1 {int operator()(int);};
class c2 {int operator()(int);};
```

> In fact, each functional behavior defined by a function object has its own type.

I don't know exactly what the author means by "functional behaviour", but I think this is just restating that two class types are separate types.

> This is a significant improvement for generic programming using templates because you can pass functional behavior as a template parameter

Meaning that you can specify a function class as a template type parameter:

```
temp<c1> thing_using_c1;
temp<c2> thing_using_c2;
```

But you can't specify a plain function that way, you'd need to supply the function some other way:

```
temp<int(int)> thing_using_f1(f1);
temp<int(int)> thing_using_f2(f2);
```

Answer (score -1):

different classes can have different functions with the same name and its parameters. but in general non class functions thats not possible